# Specify a page for turker to go with HIT Id

Tags: mechanicalturk

I create HITs to ask turkers to go to my website to perform tasks, after which I will create a separate HIT for them to verify their information and get paid. I can get the HIT Id of the payment HIT, how can I direct the turker to a webpage to get paid, without knowing the worker Id etc.?

I only know you can direct turkers to a page with group Id, like this:
https://www.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=XXXX

Can I do similar thing with HIT Id?

Comment: Why not just have them submit something in the original HIT? Seems like you're creating two steps where you only need one. (And, to answer your specific question: no, you cannot point people to a specific HIT.)

Comment: Because I need workers to do the work in my system, and when one worker take the task in my system, the HIT should be invisible to other workers, otherwise it will just waste their time to read the instructions and finally found someone else has taken the job. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: This is what an ExternalQuestion HIT is for...you're trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: The thing is that I need the worker to response as soon as possible, 'realtime' would be the best. But every time, after I post my HIT, it will be accepted in seconds, but no one do the task on my website. I guess someone is using scripts to automatically accept HITs, and only do it later. That is why I try to keep this HIT open until someone do the task on my website and open another HIT for payment. Can ExternalQuestion solve my problem?

Comment: BTW, the task is less like a form to fill in, but an interactive task, so I thought it might be better to let them login on my website rather than do it as an external HIT without registering. Is this reasonable? Looking forward to any comments.

Comment: What duration are you putting on the HITs? If your task is short and you want people to do it immediately, shorten the HIT duration to as short as possible. This will force workers to act immediately, rather than accept the HIT and revisit it later (which is a common practice).

Comment: Hi, I want the turker to take the task immediately, but the actual task will take a long time. That is why I set the time of the HIT to be very short, so it will be visible until some one actually take it on my website, and by doing this I need to pay them in another link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a hit id in the URL but you can ensure that your HITs will be assigned a different Group id if they have a different title , pay or other attribute. You can then use the group id which will be unique pet HIT.

To make things simpler for you and the workers just add the secret code or verification to your original HIT.